# Python 3.5 gbk, utf-8 convert

Tags: python, unicode, web-scraping

```
url = "http://weibo.cn/*******"
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.82 Safari/537.36','Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'}

lxml = requests.get(url, headers = headers).content
selector = etree.HTML(lxml)

i = selector.xpath('//span[@class ="ctt"]')

for each in i:
    a = each.xpath('string(.)').encode('utf-8','ignore')
    print(a)
    x = urllib.parse.unquote(str(a)).encode('utf-8')
    b = x.encode('latin-1').encode('gbk').decode('utf-8')   
    print (b)
```

the above is my codes.

The output is something such as following: `xb2\xbd\xa6\xa7` etc

these look like bytes

Can someone tell me how can I convert them to UTF-8 or strings?

I am a new bird, and interested in Python, learning how to write a spider.py

Thank you!

Comment: `\xb2\xbd\xa6\xa7` are *UTF-8 bytes*. Why are you encoding and re-encoding to Latin-1 and GBK, then decoding from UTF-8? That's... rather a non-sensical thing to do.

Comment: Because I don't know what they are. I was just trying to covert them to something which I can read and understand. I knew it doesn't make sense, as the result is same as without those encode and decode. So how can I convert bytes to strings

Comment: Why not show us `print(repr(each.xpath('string(.)'))` so we can see what is actually returned for that XPath expression? Can you tell us what output you expect to get from *that value*, without all the extra encoding and decoding and unquoting?

Comment: I thought I solved it, because when i write the output into a txt file, then i can read it in normal language. But when i open it with sublime text, it became machine language again, could you tell me why? and your answer also help me solved it. Thank you!

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve], then produce a new question about that.